# Why does Project/Properties/Android not work in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, properties, project

I have a problem when I select any project then I go to Properties and then select Android. The problem is that when I select Android it remains loading.

Comment: run eclipse in administrator mode?

Comment: no, but I'll do thanks

Comment: I ran eclipse in administrator mode and now I have  this when I go to Project/Properties/Android:                                 Unable to create the selected property page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem before and i know what i'm gonna say is somehow weird but it worked for me.
After opening **Properties** window and before clicking on **Android** re-size the **window** as small as you can such that you still can see the **Android** label to click on it :D, click the **Android** label and wait for 1-2 seconds then re-size the **window** again. i hope it works with you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version of Eclipse. That should solve the loading  issue in the Android project properties window.